# использование IPipelineBehavior библиотеки Mediatr для валидации

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Существующий код использует IPipelineBehavior и правила заданные в FluentValidator для валидации данных и выкидывает исключение в случае не валидных данных.
Данное исключение перехватывается Middleware обработчика http запроса и форматируется в нужный вид для выдачи ответа.

Вся бизнес логика переходит на использование библиотеки CSharpFunctionalExtensions для выдачи результата своей работы, а не генерации исключений.
CSharpFunctionalExtensions содержит структуру Result<T,Terror> которая обертывает ответ.
Появилась необходимость заменить выброс исключения из RequestValidationBehavior на выдачу Result.
Но RequestValidationBehavior не вызывается, при работе с Mediatr, вызывается сразу GetProductDetailQueryHandler.

Скорее всего не верно описал where ограничения для RequestValidationBehavior или не верно регистрирую в Di.

Уточнение:
при вызове

```
var vm = await Mediator.Send(new GetProductsFileQuery());
```

должен вначале вызваться `RequestValidationBehavior` и потом `GetProductDetailQueryHandler`.
Но вызывается сразу `GetProductDetailQueryHandler`, `RequestValidationBehavior` не регистрируется в конвейере обработки для типа `GetProductsFileQuery`.

```
public class GetProductDetailQuery : IRequest<Result<ProductDetailVm>>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDetailVm
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public int? SupplierId { get; set; }

    public string SupplierCompanyName { get; set; }

    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public bool Discontinued { get; set; }

    public bool EditEnabled { get; set; }

    public bool DeleteEnabled { get; set; }
}


public class GetProductDetailQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetProductDetailQuery, Result<ProductDetailVm>>
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public GetProductDetailQueryHandler(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<Result<ProductDetailVm>> Handle(GetProductDetailQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var products = new List<Product>()
        {
            new()
            {
                ProductId = 1,
                Category = new Category()
                {
                    CategoryName = "Cat1",
                    Description = "Категория 1"
                },
                Discontinued = true,
                ProductName = "Bred",
                UnitPrice = 5682
            },
            new()
            {
                ProductId = 2,
                Category = new Category()
                {
                    CategoryName = "Cat2",
                    Description = "Категория 2"
                },
                Discontinued = false,
                ProductName = "Meat",
                UnitPrice = 1258
            }
        };
        var findProd =  products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == request.Id);

        var vm = _mapper.Map<ProductDetailVm>(findProd);
        if (vm == null)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException(nameof(Product), request.Id);
        }

        return vm;
    }


    public class GetProductDetailQueryValidator : AbstractValidator<GetProductDetailQuery>
    {
        public GetProductDetailQueryValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(query => query.Id).InclusiveBetween(1, int.MaxValue);
        }   
    }
```

Не вызывается этот IPipelineBehavior

```
public class RequestValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, Result<TResponse>>
    where TRequest : IRequest<Result<TResponse>>
    where TResponse : class
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> _validators;

    public RequestValidationBehavior(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }

    public Task<Result<TResponse>> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<Result<TResponse>> next)
    {
        if (!_validators.Any())
            return next();

        var context = new ValidationContext<TRequest>(request);

        var failures = _validators
            .Select(v => v.Validate(context))
            .SelectMany(result => result.Errors)
            .Where(f => f != null)
            .ToList();


        if (failures.Any())
        {
            return Task.FromResult(Result.Failure<TResponse>("failures Join"));
        }

        return next();
    }
}
```

Регистрация в Di

```
 services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestValidationBehavior<,>));
```

Comment: Напишите более явно, в чем именно заключается вопрос.

Comment: добавил уточнение

Answer (score 0):

Использовать структуру Result не получилось напрямую. Написал обертку BaseResponse, и через рефлексию создаю ответ в случае ошибки в RequestValidationBehavior.

Проблема старого кода, в том что не регистрируется в Di  IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, Result>. Если регистрировать вручную пайплайны валидации для разных типов то все работает.

Т.е. получается 3 варианта обработки ошибок в конвеере Mediatr:

1. выкидывает пользовательский Exception c подробной инфой про ошибки
2. Возвращаем результат, в ручную регистрируем IPipelineBehavior<,> для каждого валидируемого типа.
3. Используем рефлексию для создания объекта результата в случае ошибки.

P.S. возможно более "умный" DI контейнер и регистрирует такие обработчики автоматом, стоит попробовать Autofac, Mediatr с ним работать умеет.

```
public class BaseResponse<TResponse>
{
    public BaseResponse(IList<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> errors)
    {
        Errors = errors;
        IsValid = false;
    }

    public BaseResponse(string error)
    {
        Errors = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> {new("_", new []{error})};
        IsValid = false;
    }

    public BaseResponse(TResponse item)
    {
        Item = item;
        IsValid = true;
    }

    public TResponse? Item { get; }
    public IList<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>>? Errors { get; }
    public bool IsValid { get; }


    public string ErrorsToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var (key, value) in Errors)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"{key} - '{string.Join(";", value)}'");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }



    public Result<TResponse> ToResult()=> IsValid ?
            Result.Success(Item!) :
            Result.Failure<TResponse>(ErrorsToString());
    

    public BaseResponse<TResponse> FromResult(Result<TResponse> result)=> result.IsSuccess ? 
            new BaseResponse<TResponse>(result.Value) :
            new BaseResponse<TResponse>(result.Error);

}



    public class GetProductDetailQuery : IRequest<BaseResponse<ProductDetailVm>>, IRequestPerformanceMarker
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
    
    
public class RequestValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TResponse : class
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> _validators;

    public RequestValidationBehavior(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }


    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        if (!_validators.Any())
            return await next();

        var context = new ValidationContext<TRequest>(request);
        var validationResults = await Task.WhenAll(_validators.Select(v => v.ValidateAsync(context, cancellationToken)));
        var failures = validationResults
            .SelectMany(r => r.Errors)
            .Where(f => f != null)
            .GroupBy(x => x.PropertyName,
                x => x.ErrorMessage,
                (propertyName, errorMessages) => new
                {
                    Key = propertyName,
                    Values = errorMessages.Distinct().ToArray()
                })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Values)
            .ToList();

        if (failures.Any())
        {
            var responseType = typeof(TResponse);
            var resultType = responseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var response = typeof(BaseResponse<>).MakeGenericType(resultType);
            var r= Activator.CreateInstance(response, failures) as TResponse;
            return await Task.FromResult(r!);
        }

        return await next();
    }
}
```